# Insert into | on duplicate key update to add new row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update a table, with the ability of adding new rows.
The script is updating the values, but not inserting new rows. When I add a row, it updates the first one.

This is my table:

```
 TABLE `tbl_orderdetail` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `product_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `quantity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `discount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `amount` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

And this is my update code:

```
<?php
        if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

$size = count($_POST['quantity']);
$size = count($_POST['product_name']);
$size = count($_POST['price']);
$size = count($_POST['discount']);
$size = count($_POST['amount']);

$i = 0;
while ($i<$size) {
$quantity= $_POST['quantity'][$i];
$product_name= $_POST['product_name'][$i];
$price= $_POST['price'][$i];
$discount= $_POST['discount'][$i];
$amount= $_POST['amount'][$i];
$id= $_POST['id'][$i];
$order_id= $_POST['order_id'][$i];



$query = ("INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail (id, order_id, quantity, product_name, price, discount, amount )
                             VALUES ('$id', '$order_id', '$quantity', '$product_name', '$price', '$discount', '$amount' ) 
                             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = '$quantity', product_name = '$product_name', price = '$price', discount = '$discount', amount = '$amount'");


mysql_query($query) or  die(mysql_error());
++$i;



}
header("Location: $PHP_SELF");
mysql_close();
        }
?>
```

Here's my form:

```
<form   method="post" action="">    

    <div class="box-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_orderdetail WHERE order_id=$id";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

        ?>




            <thead>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Qtde</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Unitário</th>
                <th>Desc.(%)</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th><input type="button" value="+" id="add" class="btn btn-primary"></th>

            </thead>


            <tbody id="orderdetail" class="detail">

            <?php

                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            ?>

                <tr>
                  <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" >
                    <td width="2%" class="no">1</td>
                    <td width="10%"><input type="text" id="quantity" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]" value="<?php echo $rows['quantity']; ?>"></td>
                    <td width="60%"><input type="text" id="product_name" class="form-control product_name" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $rows['product_name']; ?>"></td>
                    <td width="8%"><input type="text" id="price" class="form-control price" name="price[]" value="<?php echo $rows['price']; ?>"></td>
                    <td width="4%"><input type="text" id="discount" class="form-control discount" name="discount[]" value="<?php echo $rows['discount']; ?>"></td>
                    <td width="10%"><input type="text" id="amount" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]" value="<?php echo $rows['amount']; ?>"></td>
                    <td width="6%"><a href="#" class="remove">Excluir</td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>  
            </tbody>


            <tfoot>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" >Total  R$</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" class="total">0</th>
            </tfoot>

        </table>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update" id="update" value="Salvar">

        </form>
```

Comment: Assuming the column "id" is your primary key, have you checked your table to make sure the id's you're inputting are not duplicates?

Comment: Is your <form> generating new ID values for new rows?

Comment: @J.Han see `PRIMARY KEY (`id`)`

Comment: Yeah, I saw that later. >.> The problem, I think, is that it's inputting duplicate id, which is why it's running the update and not the insert.

Comment: @Mimispo, can you show us the form?

Comment: It sounds like your form is sending duplicate ID values which would cause your query to update instead of insert.

Comment: Yeah, your code is adding the old id values into the form so when you parse it in the PHP, you're doing a query on id values that exist in the table.

Comment: Now that I can see your form - it looks like it will always 'update' and never 'insert'.  You need another form for 'adding' a new row, then you can split that INSERT/UPDATE query into 2 separate queries.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>" >` this right here is going through each result from your select query and writing the id that exist in the table already to your hidden input id. When you submit the form, it will use old id values and you will only update and not insert.

Comment: You need to change the values that you're passing to that field.

Comment: You have to think about how to decide what "id" you're going to use and how to make it different from something that exists. For example, every ID gets multiplied to a random number.

Comment: I'm so sorry, @J.Han, but I don't get what you mean.

Comment: What @MaggsWeb said is a better idea to be honest. Split it into an update table and an insert table. Two queries. Have one dedicated to updating, and one dedicated to inserting.

Comment: I could do that, @J.Han. But I would have a complete new record, and not a new row on my old record.

Comment: No, you can have a new row on your old record. You just have to set your database connection to the same database and use the same table in your queries.

Comment: Here's you're current query:
`INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail (id, order_id, quantity, product_name, price, discount, amount )
                             VALUES ('$id', '$order_id', '$quantity', '$product_name', '$price', '$discount', '$amount' ) 
                             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantity = '$quantity', product_name = '$product_name', price = '$price', discount = '$discount', amount = '$amount'"`

Comment: Split it into:
`INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail (id, order_id, quantity, product_name, price, discount, amount )
                             VALUES ('$id', '$order_id', '$quantity', '$product_name', '$price', '$discount', '$amount' ) ` and make sure the id doesn't exist already.

`UPDATE tbl_orderdetail quantity = '$quantity', product_name = '$product_name', price = '$price', discount = '$discount', amount = '$amount'"` if the id already exists.

Comment: Thank you so much, @J.Han!! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

First: DO NOT use php's mysql library, use mysqli or PDO instead

Second: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection - best fix would be to use prepared statement (I'd advice again to look into PDO). Never ever trust anything that might be coming from a user (i.e all the POST, GET stuff).

Third: for development always display all errors, warnings, notices etc (You might have seen at least the deprecated warning for the mysql library - if working with php >= 5.5 - and the careless use of $_POST values)

Fourth: I'm sorry to say that your code makes not much of a sense to me:

1.)

```
$size = count($_POST['quantity']);
$size = count($_POST['product_name']);
// ... etc ...
$size = count($_POST['amount']);
```

Here you are only taking the size of `amount` into account. so all the lines with `$size =` before the last one are senseless.

2.) In the while loop we find lines similar to those:

```
$id= $_POST['id'][$i];
```

and `$i` is incremented until it's the size of `$_POST['amount']`. What if the size of `$_POST['id']` is not the same as the `$_POST['amount']`?

3.) You are using auto_increment for the primary key but inserting the `id` manually. I'd remove the auto_increment here.

So if I'd guess I would try echoing `$query` and check if either the while-loop is not running as often as it should or if the id values are somehow strange.

== Edit ==

I just saw your html output right now. As J.Han pointed out: your script does exactly what it was said that it should do:
You are reading all the results from the database and after editing and submitting it the new values should overwrite the old ones.

If you want to use that script with insert you have to set the `id` to one that is not yet in your database (i.e. set a value of zero in html and catch that in the php part to generate a valid new id)

Comment: how would I set a value of zero and catch it in php?